# Can Selenium (Python) detect when the JavaScript on a page hangs?

Tags: python, selenium, browser

When JavaScript code has been running without interruption for too long, browsers will bring up a modal dialog to ask the player if they want to halt the JavaScript execution. Is there a way for Selenium (specifically, I'm using the Python bindings) to detect when this happens?

My use case is that I'd like to accept arbitrary JavaScript to run (yes, I am aware this can be a security issue) and I'd like to detect if an infinite loop has been introduced by the code.

Comment: So, you want to accept such dialog, not to cancel JS execution with Selenium. Right? Can you please show that dialog so we can indicate if that is a modal dialog or alert?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to know how to either continue or stop the application.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this should check if the window becomes idle within 5 seconds:

```
driver.execute_async_script("""
  let [cb] = arguments
  Promise.race([
    new Promise((resolve) => window.requestIdleCallback(() => resolve("ok"))),
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("not ok"), 5000))
  ]).then(cb)
""")
```